# Why Ubuntu Mobile apps are from Qt?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, development

Why Ubuntu recommended Ubuntu Mobile applications to Develop on Qt ? Actually is it possible to design the Ubuntu Mobile Applications in any other languages like Java, Perl, Python or others ?

Comment: Why Qt/QML ? i think jonobacon says it well with http://www.jonobacon.org/2013/08/22/ubuntu-in-a-nutshell-the-ubuntu-sdk-and-developer-story/ and for languages http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started/

Answer (score 2):

hello @raaz i have same question.
i am java developer and i ask this same question in terms of language.

[Is it possible to develop Ubuntu Application using java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459374/is-it-possible-to-develop-ubuntu-application-using-java)

Ubuntu sdk is build for Qt only so you have to develop any Ubuntu apps in Qt Editor and Unity GUI and HTML Views.

You can use JSON, JavaScript and other things also which provided in Ubuntu Development SDK.

i got this answer only.