# Is it possible to develop Ubuntu Application using java

Tags: application-development, java, development

I am a Java Developer & want to develop application for Ubuntu.

I also visited `developer.ubuntu.com` site and successfully installed Ubuntu SDK and Editor but it is on Unity code and HTML views. I do not have any idea about `Unity development`.I have worked on Java, Android, JavaScript, php, C# & want know about developing Ubuntu application & want to know about Ubuntu Native Development & Web application in Java.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Just write your program, and run it on Ubuntu. What is it you're having problems with?

Comment: @terdon i am not familiar with unity so i ask that can i develop ubuntu apps in java ?

Comment: Ah, yes, but they don't need to have anything to do with Unity. Unity is just one of many [Desktop Environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment), your program will run on any of them.

Comment: @terdon thanks for quick replay, i will do in netbeans

Comment: @terdon have you develop ubuntu app before ?

Comment: Not in java, no. I've written a huge number of scripts and a few C programs that run on Linux. The ideas are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is a distribution of many programm written in many different languages. So to answer your qeustion: Of course you can write application for Ubuntu using Java. You will need some Java SDK and here you are. this si pretty much the same as coding for Windows beside you don't have Windows specific frameworks e.g. for UI.

Unity is a Desktop environment -- a collection of software which is adding a desktop, kind of taskbar, systray etc.

Comment: can you explain how to develop ubuntu app in java editor like in eclipse or netbeans ?

Comment: @RahulMandaliya: Just write Java code. Java is meant to let developers write code once and run it on multiple OSes (Windows, Mac, Linux, etc.). However, if you're looking to write native code that uses Ubuntu-specific functionality, you can't use Java; you can use C, C++, or HTML5.